# О чём говорит надпись красным?

Tags: сервер, webstorm, nodemon

Друзья, при запуске сервера в Terminal появляется ошибка красным:

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Не могу понять в чём проблема?
[image: Ошибка nodemon]

Comment: [nodemon] сбой приложения - ожидание изменений файла перед запуском...

Comment: А как наладить работу?

Comment: похоже, порт 9229 занят. Проверьте, какие процессы его используют

Comment: Спасибо большое!)